# i want to disable fetching in an entity @OneToMany

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a unidirectionnal association

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "candidate_id", nullable=false)
    private List<Achievement> achievements= new ArrayList<Achievement>();
```

I want to disable fetching in a way that I can fetch associated data in a separated request
eg: I don't want that hibernate returns achievements in every candidate's query

Comment: Please clear your problem and give some more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that by creating a new DTO layer `AchievementsDto` which maps the requested necessary data and send it as a response.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly when you pull the object, you don't want achievements to also be pulled from the database? If that is the case then you should use this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "candidate_id", nullable=false)
    private List<Achievement> achievements= new ArrayList<Achievement>();
```

The lazy fetch type will not fetch your one to many relationship so in this case achievements won't be fetched from the database if you fetch the object that has achievements.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `"com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;"`

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "candidate_id", nullable=false)
@JsonIgnoreProperties("achievements")
private List<Achievement> achievements= new ArrayList<Achievement>();
```

Comment: but I think it still fetching data from he database